# Add Drop Shadow to text

Tags: photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

How do I add a drop shadow (with defined distance, size etc) using Photoshop scripting?

**Current JS Code**

```
var fontSize = 14;
var fontName = "Arial-Bold"; // NB: must be postscript name of font!
// This is the colour of the text in RGB
//Click foreground colour in Photoshop, choose your colour and read off the RGB values
//these can then be entered below.
 var textColor = new SolidColor(); 
        textColor.rgb.red  = 255; 
        textColor.rgb.green =255; 
        textColor.rgb.blue = 255; 

var newTextLayer = doc.artLayers.add(); 
newTextLayer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT; 
newTextLayer.textItem.size = fontSize; 
newTextLayer.textItem.font = fontName;
newTextLayer.textItem.contents = ++Count; 
newTextLayer.textItem.color = textColor; 
newTextLayer.textItem.kind = TextType.PARAGRAPHTEXT; 
newTextLayer.textItem.height = fontSize; 
newTextLayer.textItem.width = doc.width -20;
//The line below is the text position (X Y)  IE; 10 Pixels Right 10 Pixels Down
newTextLayer.textItem.position = Array(10, 12); 
//  Can be RIGHTJUSTFIED LEFTJUSTIFIED CENTERJUSTIFIED 
newTextLayer.textItem.justification=Justification.CENTERJUSTIFIED;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no API function for this.
The best you can do is to use [Scriptlistner](http://www.earthboundlight.com/phototips/photoshop-script-listener.html).
The code that it generates then can be used in your script.

Here are some similar discussion with Scriptlistner-generated code:

http://ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=586 
or

http://ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=2207